# Highcharts - Multiple Subtitle (2)

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to have multiple sub titles (I need 2) in highcharts graph?
Just FYI - I have the title as well before sub titles.

Comment: You cannot technically have two subtitles.  However, if you describe the look you are trying to attain, maybe people can help you attain it.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just put a line break into the subtitle?

```
subtitle: {
    text: 'Line 1 of the subtitle<br>Line 2 of the subtitle' 
},
```

Comment: That's an awesome thought by the way. But implementing this is creating another problem which is that the 2nd line of subtitle is overlapping with the graph below. I tried adding margin to subtitle but its not working, any idea?

Comment: @whyA yeah you'd probably need to edit the highcharts.js to make that work since they didn't design it with two lines in mind, wouldn't really know where to start there.  Another way may be to set the X-axis maximum to something that's way above your actual maximum so that even if the 2nd line extends into the axis area there is no data it is overwriting.  Yet another option may be to use inline-CSS to make the subtitle text smaller and thus fit better.

Comment: @whyA this may help too, floating title and subtitle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/subtitle/floating/ but I probably wouldn't use that as the positioning of the title/subtitle is too hard to predict across different browsers.

Comment: That's right, I wouldn't use floating either because of different browser behavior. I guess making subtitle font smaller might be the easiest fix for this, will try that.

Comment: I tried this solution with the <br> tag.  The draw back is that HTML formatting is not supported when exporting the chart.  In my case some times the <br> is lost on the export, and in some cases it changes the alignment.  See [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#subtitle)

Comment: I had same problem. I found that increasing the margin on the Title work round the fact that the margin was not working on subtitle.

Comment: Export to image doesn't include text after the first <br/>, i.e. I am only getting one line exported

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is a built-in feature for having multiple subtitles, but I guess it should not be a lot of work to use for instance jQuery to "manually" put a div with your second subtitle on top of the chart, wherever you want it to be. You would then need to use relative or absolute positioning in CSS and make sure it has a z-index that is high enough to make it visible.

Here you can read more about how to position HTML elements: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Yeah, I also think that there is no in built feature for that. Well, I can always put in the manual html for subtitle, but the thing is that div would be outside of the svg which highcharts creates. Not a problem, but still, just wanted to check if there is a more elegant solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

A little late for this answer, but I hope this can help others.

I had a similar problem and I ended up using the renderer.text function from highcharts to add a bunch of random text all over the place.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/flacoman91/bvJaQ/

It's a bit tedious to move the text around, but it'll get the job done.

code here

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

}, function(chart) { // on complete
 var middle = chart.plotSizeX - 100;
    chart.renderer.text('Series 1', chart.plotSizeX / 2, 150)
        .attr({

        })
        .css({
            color: '#4572A7',
            fontSize: '16px'
        })
        .add();
    chart.renderer.text('Subtitle 2', chart.plotSizeX / 2, 300)
        .attr({

        })
        .css({
            color: '#4572A7',
            fontSize: '16px'
        })
        .add();

});


});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug so I've reported it here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1704

Comment: thanks for that. However, at the moment, we kept this on hold.

Answer (score 1):

You can break the line in the subtitle with a normal br-html-tag. Than you can set the title margin depending if you break the line or not.

Answer (score 0):

js

```
const graphSubtitles = `
        <span class="subtitle1">${subtitle1}</span>
        <span class="subtitle2">${subtitle2}</span>
    `;
const config = {
            title: {
                align: 'low',
                text: 'Title',
            },
            subtitle: {
                align: 'low',
                useHTML: true,
                text: graphSubtitles,
                textAlign: 'left',
            },
            ...
};
Highcharts.chart('container', config);
```

css

```
subtitle1 {
   color: red;
}
subtitle2 {
   color: blue;
}
```